# How to properly sanitize user input server side in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I know how to sanitize user input client side but I would also do it on the server side. I know that the proper place to do it is using `changeset` but up to now I cannot find an example of how to do it properly for `<script></script>` tags and other potential harmful content like SQL injection.
Because I want to allow users to change HTML content and save that HTML in the database I cannot use standard validation and I display `raw` HTML in the templates.
Can someone give me an example?

Comment: Not that it's an answer but if I were you, I'd figure out how to sanitize regular (that is non-HTML) input first and then figure out how to sanitize the special content.  Figuring out how to sanitize regular input may give you some ideas regarding how to handle the special case.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci. You're right. I'm just discovering this issue has a broader range than what I was thinking first time. I think by now I know how to handle HTML/client scripts and I'm looking towards SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

The `phoenix_html` library sanitizes user input by default:

```
<%= "<script>alert("hi")</script>" %>
```

Will display as:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert("hi")&lt;/script&gt;
```

This has to be overriden with [raw/1](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#raw/1):

```
<%= raw "<script>alert("hi")</script>" %>
```

Will display as

```
<script>alert("hi")</script>
```

If you would like to do this yourself (outside of an EEx template for example), you can use [html_escape/1](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#html_escape/1).

Comment: Sorry but my question wasn't clear enough. My goal was to learn the proper (most complete) way of getting rid of potential `<script></script>` tags and other potential user input from client side. I can't see any example of that (unless I'm missing it again in the docs...)

Comment: I'm following your thinking. You're right. But my goal was to avoid content from advanced users that can use the console to inject malicious content. That's why my goal is to sanitize again content in the server. I'm thinking about using regex (?) but I was hoping that there should already be a best practice for covering all potential malicious cases...If not, I'll take your suggestions for now.

Comment: As you have observed - you should never trust user input. Perhaps if you explained how you were "sanitizing" on the client side then it would be more clear. You can see the definition for the `html_escape` function for Plug.HTML at https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/master/lib/plug/html.ex#L15

Comment: I'm using a javascript script to do it because i'm not using Phoenix HTML forms but Ajax instead. The purpose of this is to allow administrators to change content on their websites that are not on lists. They can edit HTML content that updated that field in the database (saved as binary because of  saving images). This probably is not the best way of doing the "content management" but I'm learning a lot by doing it and it is working.